# VSI Folder in missing in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I am trying to find

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\VSI\DisableOutOfProcBuild\DisableOutOfProcBuild.exe

but the folder

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\VSI

is missing.

What should I include in the installer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found the answer. I had to install [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2022InstallerProjects).